# How to Bind Data coming from DB to spring input tag

Tags: spring, forms, input

i have the following scenario.

I have a list of auctions coming from the DB. I am displaying each auction properties on the JSP page as a record.

I am using spring 3.0.5, Tomcat 6.0.29 and eclipselink as JPA provider.

In my controller i am seeting this list as model attribute and passing it to the JSp page.

I want to use spring tags (form:input) to display the data.

Using Form backing bean we can display default values on a form. But in my case is there any way to bind data to form:input tag in the JSP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to display your data in `form:input` tags other than that you want to allow your user to edit the data. If that is not the case, then using `form:input` just to display the data is pointless.

If you want to allow your user to edit the data, how are you going to get back the changes he has done? Obviously you are going to need your Command object. So there is no reason not to use `formBackingObject()` in your `FormController` to set values in your Command object, which will be consequently displayed on your JSP. When user will make any changes and submit the form, you will get all those modified values in your Command object which you can process in `onSubmit()` method of your `FormController`.